# Visual Studio stuck on checking for updates on windows

Tags: visual-studio

The visual studio installer is stuck on checking for updates. So now I cannot modify a visual studio installation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a useful hint from [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-Installer-Checking-for-up/10037277#T-N10037573) - it works:

> Just to recap for anyone getting here: This is not an issue with your
> computer / your installation. There seem to be server side issues
> currently,
>
> The following Workarounds exist:
>
> ```
> Update your hosts file as described here
>     TL;DR: Add
>     93.184.215.201 download.visualstudio.microsoft.com
>     to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
> For those who can, there seems to be a workaround by using a VPN that goes through the US, as the US does not seem to be affected by
> ```
>
> this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem. The solution for me was setting up a VPN.